# Exact value of a trigonometric ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was asked to find the exact value of $\tan 240^\circ$. On my calculator, I type $\tan 240^\circ$, and then square the value to get a final answer of $\sqrt3$. However, the textbook answer says the exact value of $\tan 240^\circ$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

I did the calculator method for every question before that, using the exact same steps for each ratio, but now I get it wrong. Why? Why is their an exception here?

Comment: I don't know why you'd "square the value". But $\sqrt 3$ is the correct value of $\tan 240^\circ$.

Comment: HINT: break tan into $sin \over cos$ and split $240$ into $180+60$. you will get $\sqrt 3$

Comment: and btw, calculators are not the best thing to help you learn trignometric problems. They ruin the fun of it! :)

Comment: @DavidMitra If you had an understanding that the result is likely to be the square root of some rational number, and you have a simple calculator that only displays decimals, and you do not have square roots of small integers or their reciprocals memorized, this would help you deduce the value. Clearly something went wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$, and the $\sin$ and $\cos$ of $240^\circ$ are the same as $-\sin$ and $-\cos$ of $60^\circ$, you'll find that $\tan(240^\circ)$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot2 = \sqrt3$.

A piece of advice: drawing is what usually helps with these things! Squaring the value, like you said you were doing, is unclear, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\tan\left(\alpha^\circ+180^\circ\right)=\tan\left(\alpha^\circ\right).$$